# Converting results to array

Tags: postgresql, aggregate, array

I have many entities like:

user

```
id | name
-----------
 1 | Joe
 2 | David
 3 | Jane
```

cars

```
id| name 
------------
1 | cars1 
2 | cars2 
3 | cars3 
4 | cars4 
5 | cars5 
6 | cars6 
7 | cars7 
8 | cars8 
9 | cars9
```

cars_data

```
id | price  | category | uid | car_id
---+--------+----------+-----+-------
1  | 225.00 |   p1     |  1  |  1
2  | 451.00 |   p2     |  1  |  1
3  | 324.00 |   p2     |  1  |  2
4  | 784.00 |   p2     |  1  |  3
5  | 724.00 |   p3     |  1  |  2
6  | 214.00 |   p1     |  2  |  1
7  | 451.00 |   p1     |  2  |  2
8  | 926.00 |   p1     |  2  |  3
9  | 271.00 |   p2     |  2  |  3
10 | 421.00 |   p2     |  2  |  4
11 | 684.00 |   p2     |  2  |  2
12 | 124.00 |   p3     |  2  |  5
13 | 128.00 |   p3     |  2  |  1
14 | 741.00 |   p1     |  3  |  1
15 | 965.00 |   p1     |  3  |  3
16 | 124.00 |   p2     |  3  |  4
17 | 415.00 |   p2     |  3  |  1
18 | 51.00  |   p2    |  3  |   2
19 | 965.00 |   p2     |  3  |  6
```

filters

```
id  | name    |  filter          | uid
----+ --------+------------------+-----
1   | filter1 | string filters 1 |  1
2   | filter2 | string filters 2 |  1
3   | filter3 | string filters 3 |  1
4   | filter3 | string filters 3 |  1
5   | filter3 | string filters 3 |  1
6   | filter3 | string filters 3 |  1
7   | filter3 | string filters 3 |  1
8   | filter  | string filters 1 |  2
9   | filter5 | string filters 5 |  2
10  | filter6 | string filters 6 |  2
11  | filter6 | string filters 6 |  2
12  | filter6 | string filters 6 |  2
13  | filter6 | string filters 6 |  2
14  | filter7 | string filters 7 |  3
15  | filter8 | string filters 8 |  3
16  | filter8 | string filters 8 |  3
17  | filter8 | string filters 8 |  3
18  | filter8 | string filters 8 |  3
19  | filter9 | string filters 9 |  3
```

assign_filters

```
uid | category  | filter_id
----+ ----------+-----------
1   |   p1      |1          
1   |   p2      |1          
1   |   p2      |2          
1   |   p2      |3          
1   |   p3      |4          
2   |   p1      |9          
2   |   p1      |8          
2   |   p1      |13         
3   |   p2      |14         
3   |   p2      |16         
3   |   p2      |17         
3   |   p3      |19         
3   |   p3      |18         
3   |   p1      |14         
3   |   p1      |18
```

What I want is results like this:

```
uid | category  | filter_id |car_id  
----+ ----------+-----------+--------
1   |   p1      |1          |[1]
1   |   p2      |1          |[1,2,3]
1   |   p2      |2          |[1,2,3]
1   |   p2      |3          |[1,2,3]
1   |   p3      |4          |[2]
2   |   p1      |9          |[1,2,3]
2   |   p1      |8          |[1,2,3]
2   |   p1      |13         |[1,2,3]
3   |   p2      |14         |[1,2,3,4,6]
3   |   p2      |16         |[1,2,3,4,6]
3   |   p2      |17         |[1,2,3,4,6]
3   |   p3      |19         |[6,7]
3   |   p3      |18         |[6,7]
3   |   p1      |14         |[1]
3   |   p1      |18         |[1]
```

How can I change the original SQL query to give me the result above?

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=9d40f9dfe7d12c8452f00f07f7eb2ef4)

**update:**

- Each user can define a filter for himself and each filter is specific to one user.
- Each user can place cars in specific categories in the cars_data
  table.(categories is [p1,p2,p3])
- Each user can assign a number of filters to each of their categories.

I need to know which filters each user has used, and on which cars the filter has been applied.
For example, user number 1 has placed cars1, cars2, cars3 in category p1. Also, filter1, filter2, filter3 have been assigned to this category.
The result I need is this:

```
uid | category  | filter_id |car_id  
----+ ----------+-----------+--------
1   |   p2      |1          |[1,2,3]
1   |   p2      |2          |[1,2,3]
1   |   p2      |3          |[1,2,3]
```

Comment: Please put this into a fiddle (dbfiddle.uk)! You can't expect people to spend time typing in  all of **your** data! It also provides a [single source of truth] as well as eliminating duplication of effort on behalf of those who are answering - help us to help you!

Comment: For example, what is this line: `8   | filter  | string filters 1 |  2` in the filters data for? Should `filter` be `filterX` where X is a number? Put together a fiddle!

Comment: @Vérace-getVACCINATEDNOW The content of the filter field does not matter, you consider the ID.
I put all the table information in fiddle and at the end of the question I put the link. I do not know what you mean?

Comment: Sorry - must have missed the fiddle - my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT cd.uid, cd.category, f.id AS filter_id, f.name, f.filter, array_agg(cd.car_id) AS car_ids
FROM   cars_data cd
JOIN   assign_filters af USING (uid, category)
JOIN   filters f ON f.id = af.filter_id
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2,3;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f15660c5525b48809e70aa72a4f47704)*

> I need to have the `name` and `filter` fields from the `filters` table (if the filter name values are not unique)

I use `f.id AS filter_id` instead of `af.filter_id`. As `f.id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` of the `filters` table, it covers all columns of the table in `GROUP BY`, and we don't need to add any additional columns from `filters`, that you want to include in the `SELECT` list.

#### About ordinal numbers in `GROUP BY` and `ORDER BY`

Ordinal numbers in the above query reference `SELECT` list items:

```
GROUP  BY 1,2,3
ORDER  BY 1,2,3
```

Equivalent to:

```
GROUP  BY cd.uid, cd.category, f.id
ORDER  BY cd.uid, cd.category, f.id
```

The verbose form is often preferred, quite emphatically by some. But it's not without caveats. The SQL standard has peculiar rules how to resolve identifiers in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` - differently.

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-SELECT-LIST)

> An output column's name can be used to refer to the column's value in
> `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` clauses, but not in the `WHERE` or `HAVING`
> clauses; there you must write out the expression instead.

[And:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> If an `ORDER BY` expression is a simple name that matches both an
> output column name and an input column name, `ORDER BY` will interpret
> it as the output column name. This is the opposite of the choice that
> `GROUP BY` will make in the same situation. This inconsistency is made
> to be compatible with the SQL standard.

In this particular case we work with `f.id` instead of `af.filter_id`, but we want "filter_id" as alias (output column name) conflicting with the latter. Plus, there are three instances of `uid`. Two of those are merged in the `USING` clause. Plenty of ways to screw this up.

The safe way is to table-qualify everywhere as demonstrated. *Expressions* with conflicting aliases (none here) have to be spelled out repeatedly, no matter how verbose.

Ordinal numbers in `ORDER BY` and `GROUP BY` (and `DISTINCT ON`) are a simple, unambiguous alternative. Of course, changes to leading `SELECT` list items affect references, which may be welcome or not. It needs to be observed in any case, and that's the potential downside.

Comment: Group by column number is generally a bad idea, https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/86612/220697

Comment: @Charlieface: I have heard Aaron's opinion on that before, thank you. I disagree with the general statement. Positional references are just another tool with pros and cons. For starters, overly verbose code is *not* easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `STRING_AGG` function to accomplish this goal, so long as you first convert the `car_id` to a string:

```
STRING_AGG(car_id::character varying, ',') as car_id
```

This results in a SQL query that looks like:

```
SELECT cd.uid, cd.category, af.filter_id, STRING_AGG(cd.car_id::character varying, ',') as car_id
  FROM cars_data cd INNER JOIN assign_filters af ON af.uid = cd.uid and af.category = cd.category 
                    INNER JOIN filters f ON f.id = af.filter_id 
 GROUP BY cd.uid, cd.category, af.filter_id
 ORDER BY cd.uid;
```

Which gives you:

```
uid | category | filter_id | car_id
1   | p1       | 1         | 1
1   | p2       | 1         | 3,2,1
1   | p2       | 2         | 1,3,2
1   | p2       | 3         | 1,2,3
1   | p3       | 4         | 2
2   | p1       | 8         | 3,2,1
2   | p1       | 9         | 3,1,2
2   | p1       | 13        | 3,1,2
3   | p1       | 14        | 1,3
3   | p1       | 18        | 3,1
```

If you want the brackets, those can be concatenated:

```
CONCAT('[', STRING_AGG(car_id::character varying, ','), ']') as car_id
```

Comment: You can use `::TEXT` instead of `::CHARACTER VARYING` - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4849030/470530) - in this context, it's simply more readable!

Comment: No need to convert anything to a string - see  [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b69800dd0f444a03017093e45d6ce16b).

Comment: If majid wants an array, then `array_agg()` is probably a better choice. If a JSON value is needed then `jsonb_agg()` would be more appropriate.

Comment: Considering the use of group by, what can be done if I need to have the name and filter fields from the filters table (if the filter name values are not unique)

Comment: @majd Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69794950/470530) for the use of `DISTINCT`... or [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=b69800dd0f444a03017093e45d6ce16b).